# Is there any significance of having a static keyword for a dynamically created array?

Tags: c++, arrays, static, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am allowed to execute this code without an error. So I believe C++ allows this.
Ex:

```
char *foo (char *start, int n) {
    static char* temp; //Does this have any significance?
    temp = new char[n];
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
        temp[(n-1)-j]=start[j];
    return temp;
}

int main(){
    char *c;
    char a[6]={'1','2','3','4','5','\0'};
    c = a;
    int n = sizeof(a);
    c = foo(c,n);
    delete []c; //Does this delete the static array created in foo()?
    return 0;
}
```

P.S.- I know there is a better way of reversing an array but the Q is not focused on that. I just was not able to come up with a better example.:)

EDIT: I understand temp gets created in heap and I don't need to use static. But does static keyword in variable declaration make any difference while creating a dynamic array in memory mapping, etc.?

Comment: Yes, `delete []c;` deletes the array allocated in `foo`. Little of your code makes sense, but this part is correct.

Comment: Why is this variable static?

Comment: @ Igor Ok, Thanks! That helps.
I think I posted an incorrect version of code before. I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: Yes because foo returns pointer.

Comment: @tkausl I believe I cannot return a local array so I created it static.

Comment: If you allocate dynamically,you can return pointer.

Comment: There's no material difference between the original code and the current one. It still makes little sense, but `delete []c;` part is still correct.

Comment: An array created by `new` isn't local.

Comment: 'Dynamically created static' is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: As @Igor Tandetnik said, the code still makes little sense. For example, `sizeof(c)` will not return the length of the array `a` as you might expect but the size of `c`, which is of type `char *`, i.e. a pointer value and therefore probably `8` on a 64 bit machine.

Comment: @tkausl
Thanks for pointing that out. Rookie mistake. I understand now.

Comment: As @tkausl indicates, all of this will work just fine if the `static` keyword is removed.  In fact, if the function is use in a multi-threaded fashion, the `static` keyword will cause problems.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Your code makes more sense without the `static`. Instead of `sizeof(c)`, you should use (`sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])`).

Comment: @StephanLechner You are correct. I edited my code.

Comment: It's true that returning the address of a local variable (which can be a local array) isn't useful in C or C++, because by the time that pointer would be dereferenced, the local variable doesn't exist anymore.

But you are not doing so by `return temp;` in your code (even if `temp` is not `static`). That would be `return &temp;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `temp` variable is static, the memory block whose address it stores is dynamically allocated (`new char[n]`) and freed (`delete []c`).

They are different objects.

The array doesn't care about `temp` (it doesn't even know about it). You can store the address of the array in many variables; this doesn't change its behaviour in any way.

> I understand `temp` gets created in heap.

`temp` is not created in the heap. It is a local variable; local variables are not stored in the heap.

> ```
>    static char* temp; //Does this have any significance?
> ```

The `static` keyword makes `temp` a permanent variable, that exists since the program starts until it ends. The `static` keyword ensures its value is not lost when the function ends. Every time the function `foo()` is executed (except the first one), the value of `temp` is the same it was the last time when it ran.

But, being a local variable, `temp` is available only in the `foo()` function.

The value of `temp` is a memory address. The address of the block allocated using `new char[n]`. This block of memory is allocated in the heap and it is valid until it is released (using `delete []c`). It can be accessed from `main()` too, given its address is somehow available in the `main()` function. And it is available because the call to the `foo()` function returns it and `main()` stores it in `c`.

> ```
>     delete []c; //Does this delete the static array created in foo()?
> ```

No, it deletes (in fact, releases) only the array (created in `foo()`). The static variable (`temp`) is not affected in any way.

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful. I have an understanding of what exactly is happening in this code now.

Answer (score 0):

You allocated some memory with `new[]` and you released it with `delete[]`. That's what you're supposed to do. You can manipulate a pointer to that memory however you want so long as you pass the same value to `delete[]` that you got from `new[]`.

Your function should be (and is) returning the value it got from `new[]`. It can store that in a temporary if it wants to. The error is returning a pointer or reference to a temporary. Returning the value of a temporary is fine -- otherwise it would be almost impossible to return anything other than a constant or a pointer or reference to a parameter passed by reference or a global.